# Fiddler doesn't capture Https requests that made by HttpClient and HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, https, fiddler

I'm trying to get some resources from the website using simple HttpClient and HttpClientHandler classes. When i use Http, it works well but in case of Https it doesn't work. The following code is my settings:

```
        var url="https://www.someurl.com"; 
        var proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;

        htmlHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        htmlHandler.UseProxy = true;
        htmlHandler.Proxy = proxy;
```

I also changed settings of .exe.config file and it didn't worked. I should note that just one entry in fiddler was shown:
[image]

Comment: Https uses port forwarding to a different IP address (IP the proxy server).  You probably have filtering turned on so you aren't seeing all the data.

Comment: If you mean filtering of Fiddler is turned on, No it's not. I'm not filtering anything.

Comment: Have you enabled HTTPS decryption in the Fiddler options?

Comment: Yes. Iv'e enabled HTTPS decryption and it works with all other programs like chrome.

Comment: Still think filtering is enabled.  You can see "Tunnel to" which is part of https.  The 200 result (DONE) indicates all data has been returned.  Port 443 is the SSL.  So everything is working properly.  The only thing suspicious is the body size is zero.

Comment: Https uses a different Command and Data Port.  Port 443 is the Command port.  So it looks like the connection completed on the Command Port because you got the 200 Done.  So now you need to send/receive data on the data port.

Comment: Other HTTPS traffics are captured well. In case of other programs like chrome entries like this are logged in sessions section but after them the main traffic occurs. I should note that every communication to the real server is done perfectly and i can get all data.

Comment: No, HTTPS does not use a "command and data port" like FTP does.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Tunnel line in the picture you included a reference to the site to which the .NET client is trying to send traffic? Or is it unrelated? (What is the Process column?)

What do you see on the LOG tab when traffic is sent to Fiddler?

The most likely explanation is that the Fiddler Root Certificate is not trusted by the account in which the .NET client application runs. Fiddler allows you to trust the Fiddler Root certificate on a machine-wide basis which will resolve such issues.